# How to adjust the width of all elements in Bootstrap 4 that are inside a .input-group class?

Tags: bootstrap-4

In a PHP based project, I use Bootstrap 4 (v4.1.0). In some portion of some forms I need to use **.input-group** class and **.input-group-append** class to combine closely related fields. Here is a sample code:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="condition_category" class="form-control-label">Condition Category &amp; Code:&nbsp;<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <select name="condition_category" id="condition_category" class="form-control">
                <option value="Value">Text</option>
            </select>

        <div class="input-group-append">
            <select name="condition_code" id="condition_code" class="form-control condition_code">
                <option value="Value">Text</option>
            </select>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything is OK except, I can't control the width of those elements. One example is in the below image:

[image]

You may notice that two fields have two different widths. But I want both will have the same width (except the show button in the image).

Can anyone tell me how can I handle the widths (I mean both select fields will have the same width) using Bootstrap 4?

- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to style with `.input-group *` css selector. But i think is better to use `row` `col` grid system instead of adjust width manually.

Answer (score 0):

In best way you can achieve this by  wrapping in bootstrap structure and then set `padding` and `margin` between element to 0.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">text Box</div>
   <div class="col-md-2">btn 1</div>
   <div class="col-md-2">btn 2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

So exact classes would be like for every device is

```
col-8 col-sm-8 sol-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8

col-2 col-sm-2 sol-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2

col-2 col-sm-2 sol-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2
```

Manual width is not an good option.

Hope this will help you.